# how to create my ouw schematics with nest cli

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Currently I work in back-end proyects build with Nestjs and i have found an interesting project structure that is repeated in every project I build.

I would like to have the option to create projects with the help of the CLI by creating my own command.

something like this:

`nest new myproject --schematics=myschematic`

anyone know if this can be done?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/usages#nest-new), there is the option of using the `--collection` option, which allows you to specify the the schematics collection. Usage is like so:

```sh
nest new myproject --collection=myschematiccollection
```

It is also aliased as `-c`

Comment: thanks!, where can I find the documentation of how to make schematics collection?

Comment: There's not necessarily an easy "how-to" on this, but [Angular's docs](https://angular.io/guide/schematics) are pretty good for it, and as Nest makes use of the `ng-builder` it's the same kind of set up.